# AngularJS : Need help to unit test a factory with promise

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, promise

I have a factory that uses a promise to resolve a json file.
It should only resolve this file the first time and return the result when called again.

Here is the factory

```
app.factory('getServerConfig', function ($q, $http, serverConfig) {

  return function (fileName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (serverConfig.loaded) {
      deferred.resolve("alreadyLoaded");
    } else {
      $http.get(fileName).then(function (result) {
        serverConfig.setConfig(result.data);
        deferred.resolve("loaded");
      }, function (result) {
        deferred.reject();
      });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };
})
```

And how I test it :

```
it('should say hallo to the World', inject(function(getServerConfig) {
    var promiseResult;

    getServerConfig("server-config.json").then(function (result) {
      promiseResult = result;
    });

    rootScope.$apply();
    expect(promiseResult).toBe('loaded');
}));
```

Unfortunately, it looks likes promiseResult is never set.
Here is a plunker with the code : http://plnkr.co/edit/uRPCjuUDkqPRAv07G5Nx?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $httpBackend demands a `flush()` (take a look at [Flushing HTTP requests](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend)), so you can mimic `$http` asynchronous behavior in your test.

To solve it, store a reference of `$httpBackend` (or inject it again) and call $httpBack.flush() after the request has been made.

Look:

```js
it('should say hallo to the World', inject(function(getServerConfig, $httpBackend) {
  var promiseResult;

  getServerConfig("server-config.json").then(function (result) {
    promiseResult = result;
  });

  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(promiseResult).toBe('loaded');
}));
```

If you gonna use `$httpBackend` in most of your specs, consider storing it in a local variable, and set it in `beforeEach`.

Comment: Ah thanks. I did use flush but inside the beforeEach function, that's why it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: How would you test a controller that depended on this service? Thanks.

Comment: The best way to test your controller would be mocking this service and returning a know promise, that you can control the resolution time. If you don't want to mock it, just call `$httpBackend.flush()` the same way and check if controller reacted the way you expect. Create a new question (this is off this topic) and post some code so I can help you more.

Comment: Is the `rootScope.apply()` really necessary?

Comment: Thanks @KeesdeKooter. It's probably not necessary indeed, as `$http` already [invokes a `$rootScope.$apply` after resolving he promises](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L983). Will remove from the response.